# Add link to contacts in outlook Appointment Module Form using custom fields

Tags: vb.net, outlook, exchangewebservices, outlook-2010

I'm a long date leecher of this site... this is the first time I'm not able to find a response (Google didn't help too).
Well, what I am trying to do is to add an active link to a contact to a custom field in an Appointment Module Form.
I can put the address I want in the appointment custom fields using this code (vb.net):

```
Dim extendedPropertyDefinition = New ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, "MyField", MapiPropertyType.String)
item.SetExtendedProperty(extendedPropertyDefinition, "address@iwant.com")
```

I am able to view MyField using a custom field in my Appointment Module Form.
Setting "To" field to the value (in custom field properties) i can transform the e-mail into the corresponding contact name (obviously if it exists in contacts list).
Here comes the trouble:
I would like to add a link to contact card when clicking the contact name.
I don't really know if it is even possible...
Thank you very much for any help... "It is not possible" will be an appreciated response too.

Comment: What is item.SetExtendedProperty?  Please provide more context

Comment: You can find a complete view of extended properties here:[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633691%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)